# Perl6 REPL - Variable is not declared

Tags: raku

How do I define a variable that can be used in the next statement?

so far
`my $a = 0`
and 
`$a = 0`
cannot be used after the line they are declared on without getting:
`Variable '$a' is not declared`.

Comment: should be working again: https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/commit/643c0f902598a49de698a27eda75c52ef5b81c62

Answer (score 2):

This works in a recent perl6 - what does "perl6 --version" say for you?

```
$ perl6 --version
This is Rakudo version 2016.07.1 built on MoarVM version 2016.07
implementing Perl 6.c.
$ perl6
You may want to `panda install Readline` or `panda install Linenoise` or use rlwrap for a line editor

To exit type 'exit' or '^D'
> my $a = 4;
4
> $a;
4
>
```

Comment: I just rebuilt (2016.07.1-204-g0f420ad) and can confirm the problem; also, cf http://irclog.perlgeek.de/perl6/2016-08-17#i_13035898

Comment: This is definitely fixed now, sorry for the bug (which I might have caused :) ).